# pass the php variable from one page to other page

Tags: php

Well, I just started to work on server side scripting , I chose PHP, So let me explain where Im getting troubled.

This is very a quite simple questions.See, I have some links like these on my page1.php

```
 <a href="page2.php">profile</a>
 <a href="page3.php">photos</a>
```

Now when user jumps to page2.php or page3.php, I also want to pass the user unique ID to the corresponding page, say his email.so that i can update the page2.php according to the username.

When I googled, I heard lots of contradictions , some people were explaining to use `session_start()` and some people explains `cookies` and some people says `POST` and `GET`methods. Some people said its easy to hack when  you use GET or POST method and some people answered Cookies are client side and it disconnects from server and after hearing all those I decided to use `session_start()`

But as im a newbee I dont know what to chose,which is the best way.Could anyone kindly explain me which is the best solution to use and why? and also please provide some sample example so that i can understand it much better.Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order of preference as a solution for the problem you have presented in your question.

### Sessions

As this is details of the current user the easiest way to complete this is to use PHPs sessions. This will allow you to access the details in a super global array called [`$_SESSION` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) from any page that calls the [`session_start()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function. This should appear before any output is sent to the browser so it is usually put at the very top of the PHP script.

Each user has their own session on the server and `session_start()` automagically provides your script with the right data for the current user.

#### page1.php

```
session_start();
$users_email_address = 'example@example.org'; // source from DB or whatever
$_SESSION['email_address'] = $users_email_address;
```

#### page2.php and/or page3.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['email_address'];
```

Please see the manual [documentation for `session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) for more examples.

### Use HTTP GET parameters

This works best for URLs that you may want to share - so search results pages or perhaps pagination.

Passing user details in this manner is not ideal as the user can easily change the URL in the browsers address bar. So they could change their email address to someone elses and fool your script.

### Using cookies

Storing user data in cookies is not a brilliant idea as a user is able to edit cookies as they are stored on their machine.

Also cookies have a size limit of 4KB and get sent with every request header to the server - thus slowing your site down.

### Using HTTP POST parameters

This the very least recommended method for doing this. POST is intended for receiving data to save it on the server and not for navigation. If the user were to press back on `page3.php` then they would be shown a "do you want to resumbit this form" message by their browser. Pretty unintuitive for a user who thought that they had just clicked a link and not submitted a form.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use session variables ( such as `$_SESSION['variable_name'];` ).

If you involve form submission, use `POST` method.

If you only get simple information by setting up parameters, use `GET` method.

Answer (score 0):

When the user id is set you want to add it to a session. A session is basically a variable that is available over all your pages.

When you set your sessions you want to have `session_start();` at the very top of your page. It needs to be before the `<html>` tag.

Set your session like so `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;`

You can then recall the value of the session on any page like this `echo 'User id: ' . $_SESSION['user_id'];`

This will output: User id: 1

There's a lot of info in the manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Point taken. It's just a bit more user friendly than the manual for beginners I found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of those.

**Session**

This is the best as the email address is stored in the server side. There is no way someone can get hold of the value and try to do bad things with it.

**GET**

Although this achives what you want by appending to the URL like `page2.php?email=someone@example.com`, it's easily readable in the browser address bar. It's like you don't store this value anywhere, just pass it between pages.

**POST**

This is similar to `GET` but that the parameter gets passed under the hoods. The user can still find this out if he uses plugins to his browser. Like `GET`, here also the value isn't really stored anywhere. To do a `POST`, however, you'll need to have a form on your page. Think of it like a form where you ask the user to input his email address.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
</form>
```

In the above example, you can read the value of `email` in `page2.php` by doing `$_POST["email"]`.

Note that if you change the method to `get`, it becomes same as a `GET` request.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
</form>
```

Here, you can read the value of `email` in `page2.php` by doing `$_GET["email"]`.

**COOKIES**

This works by storing a value on the user's browser. The least recommended of all approaches as the user need not have his cookies feature turned on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the answer of Treffynnon:
actually page2.php should be page1.php

Manual about session:
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php

session_start() must come before all html code or echo in php. In other words: before everything that generate html's code.

Answer (score 0):

sessions are the best choice .Because sessions were one solution invented to over come the 
STATELESS nature of the web pages .

sessions are very simple to understand and use . each user will be having an session .